# Sphinx wildcard not match all as expected

Tags: wildcard, sphinx

my query is:

```
select * from words where match('*а$') LIMIT 1000000 OPTION max_matches=1000000;
```

I want to find all word which ending "a"; but sphinx return just part of it - not all

my config is:

```
index words
{
        source = words
        path = /var/www/sphinx/words
        docinfo = extern
        mlock = 0
        #min_word_len = 1
        #morphology = stem_ru
        charset_table = 0..9, A..Z->a..z, _,-, a..z, U+410..U+42F->U+430..U+44F, U+430..U+44F
        min_infix_len = 1
        index_exact_words=1
        expand_keywords=0
        dict=keywords
}
```

in result just words which have exact "a" at end:

```
word a
word-a
word(a)
word2 a
etc...
```

But I need exact match like regex "a$" - wordA, wwwordA, wordsA

Answer (score 1):

`$` is field end operator -  it will return a match if the words is the last (or only) one word in a field. If you just need all words ending in `a` you only need `MATCH('*a')`.